# Change the download directory on Edge using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I was working on a bot that is downloading some excel documents, put I can't change the download address.
This is the current part of the code:

```
options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.add_argument("--guest")
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

prefs = {
    "translate": {"enabled": False},
    'profile.default_content_settings.popups': 0,
    'download.default_directory': r"C:\Users\Elias\Escritorio\Nueva carpeta",
    'directory_upgrade': True,         
}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)


driver = webdriver.Edge(options)
```

I have tried this, but it isn't working:

```
prefs = {
    "translate": {"enabled": False},
    'profile.default_content_settings.popups': 0,
    'download.default_directory': r"C:\Users\Elias\Escritorio\Nueva carpeta",
    'directory_upgrade': True,         
}
```

Also this:

```
prefs = {
    "translate": {"enabled": False},
    'profile.default_content_settings.popups': 0,
    'download.default_directory': r"C:\Users\Elias\Escritorio\Nueva carpeta",
    'download.prompt_for_download': False,
    'downlond.directory_upgrade': True,
}
```